# Copy directories when their name matches -Like txt files

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise, powershell-1.0

I am trying to copy a bunch of directories.  I have text files which have a similar name and I need to match the directories to those text files to determine which directories to copy.

This is what I have done and I can't figure out how to fix it.  I am going around in circles.

```
$destination = "..\..\$args\Images\"
$txtfiles = Get-ChildItem $destination -Include *.txt
$source = "..\..\..\Images\" | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Where-Object { $_.Name -Like "*$txtfiles*" } | Copy-Item $destination
```

An example of a txt file: `1e03655b-0aac-48b2-82f3-75942084af7a.txt`

and folder: `name.1e03655b-0aac-48b2-82f3-75942084af7a`

So I need to find the folders that match the txt files and copy the folder to the txt file directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to expand the BaseName properties of those text files (to cut off the .txt part) and have an array of strings such as:

```
1e03655b-0aac-48b2-82f3-75942084af7a
1e03655b-0aac-48b2-82f3-75942084af7b
1e03655b-0aac-48b2-82f3-75942084af8g
1e03655b-0aac-48b2-82f3-75942084afba
```

Then your `$source =` line needs to pull a directory listing and not just pipe a string down the pipeline, and then I would suggest matching the directory names with a regex match, and checking to see if that match is `-in $txtfiles`.

```
$destination = "..\..\$args\Images\"
$txtfiles = Get-ChildItem $destination -Filter *.txt | Select -ExpandProperty BaseName
$source = "..\..\..\Images\"
GCI $source -Directory | ?{ $_.Name -match "(\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12})$" } | %{If($Matches[1] -in $txtfiles){Copy-Item $_.FullName $destination}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  This doesn't work for me. No errors.

Comment: That's because the FileSystem provider is dumb as a box of rocks. I changed -Include to -Filter and it works now.

Comment: I still can't seem to get it to work.  Getting error this time - `Copy-Item: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '..\..\passed_directory\Images\'.`

Comment: Sorry, I retyped it instead of copy/paste and evidently fat fingered it. I had a `-` in the 'Copy-Item - $_.FullName $destination' command before the source path that was screwing it up. With that removed it works. Really sorry about that.

Comment: OK, it copies the directories, but not the contents.

Comment: You didn't say anything about copying files. There are files in the folders? Add -Recurse to the end of the Copy-Item command

Comment: Yeah sorry, my bad.  Yeah I got it working with recurse.  I still get errors though, can't seem to find the source.  But it is doing what I need it to despite the error.

Comment: If you would like to update your question with the code you are using, and what the error is I'll see what I can figure out. Aside from that there's always `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Comment: It's OK, my fault again.  Everything work's as expected.  Excellent, thank you.